# Images in the 'drawable' folder are resized automatically?

Tags: android

I have a 1280x720px image in the res/drawable folder (not the drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, etc. folder). But at runtime the size is 2560x1440px. How is this possible? Does android resize the images in the drawable folder?

Here is the code:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.start_image_left);
    int h = bitmap.getHeight(), w = bitmap.getWidth();
```

I'm testing this on a Motorola Moto G gen2.

Comment: I think the only way to guarantee no scaling is to use the drawable-nodpi folder.

Comment: @zgc7009: What do you mean by 'how you are loading your image'? I just put it in the resource, and later I get it out. And when is necessary to scale?

Comment: I was looking at the question on my phone and didn't see your code in your question. I thought you loading it into a view, which would cause scaling. Android will scale images in the drawable folder, I am not sure how scaling is handled but it does scale them. The only way to guarantee no scaling (I think) is to place your files in the nodpi qualified drawable folder.

Comment: Since your phone is an **xxhdpi** device, try putting your image  in the `drawable-xxhdpi` folder (create it, if not existing).

Comment: drawable's content is scaled with the the screen's density.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's really no reason you should ever put a bitmap into the root `drawable` directory. It should typically be used for XML drawables only. Bitmaps in the `drawable` directory will essentially be handled as if they were in `drawable-mdpi` (scaled up proportionally for other densities).

If your goal is to have a bitmap image that is the same pixel size on all densities, you need to put it in `drawable-nodpi`. This will cause it to not be scaled.

Comment: if you don't want that (why ever) and you are using `BitmapFactory.decodeResource`; you can also disable scaling with `BitmapFactory.Options#inScaled = false;`

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, Android automatically scales your image based on the current device configuration. If however, you dont want that behaviour, you can create a bitmap resource file, put in the `drawable` folder and point it to the drawable you want to use like this

`<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
        android:src="@drawable/yourDrawableHere"
        android:gravity="center" />`

By specifying the center gravity, android will not scale your image no matter what.

To use this bitmap resource file, in your code, retrieve it like this

`Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourBitmaoResourceFileName);`

Comment: you can put it into the `drawable-nodpi` folder instead of this using hack

Comment: True, yes, because answer like yours has been said above so I just want to contribute another way to fix it.